# Во время скролинга viewpager на Android monitor выводится Skipped 39 frames! ... much work on its main thread

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager

Во время скролинга viewpager на Android monitor выводится Skipped 39 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread. и приложения тормозит

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if(pos == null && getArguments() != null) {
        id_fasl = getArguments().getString("id_fasl");
        id_table = getArguments().getString("id_table");
    }else{
        pos = 0;
    }
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_screen_one, container,false);

    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    Tasker tasker = new Tasker();
    tasker.execute();


    mSlidingTabLayout = (SlidingTabLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.sliding_tabs);
    mSlidingTabLayout.setCustomTabColorizer(new SlidingTabLayout.TabColorizer() {
        @Override
        public int getIndicatorColor(int position) {
            return getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary);
        }
        @Override
        public int getDividerColor(int position) {
            return getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark);
        }
    });
    mSlidingTabLayout.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            ((ModdaActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setTitle(bob_name[mViewPager.getCurrentItem()]);
        }
        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
        }
    });

}

class SamplePagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return kol;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object o) {
        return o == view;
    }
    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return "БОБИ " + (id_bob[position]);
    }
    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        View view = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.pager_item,
                container, false);
        container.addView(view);
        txt = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.item_text);
        txt.setText(moddas[position]);
        ((ModdaActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setTitle(bob_name[mViewPager.getCurrentItem()]);
        return view;
    }
    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        container.removeView((View) object);
    }
}
```

Comment: @metalurgus, думаю, это можно в ответ написать)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, если вы так считаете...

Comment: @metalurgus, ну, от этого же ничего, вроде, не падает... Сам такое видел и, просто забив, ничего не потерял)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, я тоже не обращаю внимания на это.

Answer (score 1):

Это нормальная реакция на тяжелые операции в `UI`-потоке. Видимо, у вас тяжелый `View`/слабый дивайс.

Comment: использовано SlidingTabLayout и SlidingTabStrip